# Override Settings for Tests of Django Rest Framework Throttling

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, throttling

I'm trying to test a custom user throttling:

```
def get_user_rate(user):
    # Returns tupple (user plan quota, total seconds in current month)

class SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    # Define a custom scope name to be referenced by DRF in settings.py
    scope = "subscription"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def custom_throttle_success(self):
        """
        Inserts the current request's timestamp along with the key
        into the cache.
        """
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        return True

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Override rest_framework.throttling.SimpleRateThrottle.allow_request

        Check to see if the request should be throttled.
        On success calls `throttle_success`.
        On failure calls `throttle_failure`.
        """

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            limit, duration = get_user_rate(request.user)
            # Override the default from settings.py
            self.duration = duration
            self.num_requests = limit
            
        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        # Drop any requests from the history which have now passed the throttle duration
        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()

        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()
        
        return self.custom_throttle_success()
```

In `settings.py` I have added a default throttle rate of 10/second just for security (it is passed first on `DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES`):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
        'api.throttling.SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'user': '10/second',
    }
}
```

The test I want to write is very simple, if I have a user with a given plan, I want to check that the user can make up to N requests without being throttled:

```
class TestThrottling(TestCase):
    def test_plan_quota(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@email.com', password='test')
        Plan.objects.create(user=user, plan=1) # plan 1 has N requests per month                                                                       
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)                
        auth_client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        
        url = reverse('some_endpoint')

        for k in range(N): # Being N the user plan quota
            response = auth_client.get(url)
            self.assertNotEqual(response.status_code, 429)
        
        response = auth_client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 429)
```

The problem that I have is the default 10/second rate that there is on settings, because it breaks the loop before reaching the user plan quota. I want to delete this default rate from settings to check that my throttling works fine, I could also set a timer to avoid making more than 10 requests per second, but the plans quotas are very high and it'd take hours. I tried overriding settings adding:

```
# Override default user throttling
new_config = settings.REST_FRAMEWORK.copy()
new_config['DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES'] = ['api.throttling.SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle']

@override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK=new_config)
def test_plan_quota(self):
    ...
```

This way I could remove the default 10/second rate for the test, unfortunately this isn't working because sometimes DRF [doesn't update settings](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2466). Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `UserRateThrottle` will always be applied, so even if you get the tests working, subscribers will still be bound to the default `UserRateTrottle` rate in production.

The solution is to have both types of throttling in one class:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'api.throttling.SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'user': '10/second',
    }
}
```

And then differentiate the rate and duration based on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
class SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    # Define a custom scope name to be referenced by DRF in settings.py
    scope = "subscription"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_user_rate(self, user):
        # Returns tuple (user plan quota, total seconds in current month)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return (custom_subscriber_rate, custom_subscriber_duration)
        else:
            return (default_rate, default_duration)

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        # Set cache_key scope and ident based on subscriber or anon.
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
            ident = request.user.pk
            scope = self.scope
        else:
            ident = self.get_ident(request)
            scope = 'anon'

        return self.cache_format % {'scope': scope, 'ident': ident}

    def custom_throttle_success(self):
        """
        Inserts the current request's timestamp along with the key
        into the cache.
        """
        self.history.insert(0, self.now)
        self.cache.set(self.key, self.history, self.duration)
        return True

    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        """
        Override rest_framework.throttling.SimpleRateThrottle.allow_request

        Check to see if the request should be throttled.
        On success calls `throttle_success`.
        On failure calls `throttle_failure`.
        """

        # Get limit and duration for all requests...
        limit, duration = self.get_user_rate(request.user)
        self.duration = duration
        self.num_requests = limit
            
        self.key = self.get_cache_key(request, view)
        if self.key is None:
            return True

        self.history = self.cache.get(self.key, [])
        self.now = self.timer()

        # Drop any requests from the history which have now passed the throttle duration
        while self.history and self.history[-1] <= self.now - self.duration:
            self.history.pop()

        if len(self.history) >= self.num_requests:
            return self.throttle_failure()
        
        return self.custom_throttle_success()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a couple of questions seeing your code, first one is how could a request be anonymous if it needs a valid token [which is created using a User object](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py). In this case, I would not be able to use both throttling rates at the same time. I wanted to keep a default user rate of 10/second for safety, but I'll try using your code and see how it goes.

Comment: @Stack You can have token authentication set up, but not necessarily use it for all API views. So, in theory, you could have endpoints that did not require a token and therefore did not require a user, in which case `SubscriptionDailyRateThrottle` would apply a default rate limit. I don't know if that's the case in your project, but as you said, it seems like a good fallback for safety.

Comment: I understand, thanks for clarifying, in my case all endpoints require authentication but I think I can use your code to solve my issue.